# Will relative velocity with respect to electrons effect current in wire and magnetic field produced by wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, homework-and-exercises

**Question:**

> consider a long, straight wire of cross-sectional area $A$ carrying a
>   current $i$. Let there be $n$ free electrons per unit volume. An observer
>   places himself on a trolley moving in the direction opposite to the
>   current with a speed $v = \frac{i}{nAe}$ and separated from the wire by a
>   distance $r$. The magnetic field seen by the observer is very nearly

**My Answer:**

> Zero. Because current is $neAv$ where $v$ is drift velocity of electrons. Relative velocity between him and electrons is zero. So, no flow of charge through any cross-section according to him. So no current. So no magnetic field.

**Actual answer:**

> $\frac{\mu\ i}{2\cdot\pi\cdot r}$  where $\mu$ is the permeabilty of free space.

Comment: And what question are you asking _us_? If it is "what did I do wrong" think about what's in the wire apart from electrons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike an electron beam, a wire carrying a current contains positive charges as well, and these charges move with respect to the moving observer.

Comment: Opposite to current=along with electrons.

Comment: @Manishearth: I stand corrected.

Comment: You may want to un-edit the edit then =P